# Grey out shipping method WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a plugin or a programmatic way to have a shipping method constantly greyed out in the checkout page of WooCommerce, like in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick 'n dirty solution to show all disabled shipping methods (unselectable) below the enabled ones (place in your-child-theme-directory/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * Shipping Methods Display
 *
 * In 2.1 we show methods per package. This allows for multiple methods per order if so desired.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$formatted_destination    = isset( $formatted_destination ) ? $formatted_destination : WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $package['destination'], ', ' );
$has_calculated_shipping  = ! empty( $has_calculated_shipping );
$show_shipping_calculator = ! empty( $show_shipping_calculator );
$calculator_text          = '';
?>
<tr class="woocommerce-shipping-totals shipping">
    <th><?php echo wp_kses_post( $package_name ); ?></th>
    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $package_name ); ?>">
        <?php if ( $available_methods ) : ?>
            <ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
                <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php
                        if ( 1 < count( $available_methods ) ) {
                            printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" />', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), esc_attr( $method->id ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        printf( '<label for="shipping_method_%1$s_%2$s">%3$s</label>', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package( $package );
                $available_methods_ids = array_values(array_map( function($element){ return $element->method_id; }, $available_methods));
                $disabled_shipping_methods = array_filter(
                        $shipping_zone->get_shipping_methods( false ), 
                        function($value) use ($available_methods_ids) {
                            return (array_search($value->id, $available_methods_ids) === false); 
                        } 
                    ); 
                    foreach ( $disabled_shipping_methods as $method ) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php
                        printf( '<input disabled type="radio" />' );
                        printf( '<label style="opacity: 0.5" >%1$s</label>', $method->title );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php if ( is_cart() ) : ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-shipping-destination">
                    <?php
                    if ( $formatted_destination ) {
                        // Translators: $s shipping destination.
                        printf( esc_html__( 'Shipping to %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' );
                        $calculator_text = esc_html__( 'Change address', 'woocommerce' );
                    } else {
                        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_estimate_html', __( 'Shipping options will be updated during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
        elseif ( ! $has_calculated_shipping || ! $formatted_destination ) :
            if ( is_cart() && 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' ) ) {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_not_enabled_on_cart_html', __( 'Shipping costs are calculated during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
            } else {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_may_be_available_html', __( 'Enter your address to view shipping options.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
            }
        elseif ( ! is_cart() ) :
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html', __( 'There are no shipping options available. Please ensure that your address has been entered correctly, or contact us if you need any help.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
        else :
            // Translators: $s shipping destination.
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', sprintf( esc_html__( 'No shipping options were found for %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' ) ) );
            $calculator_text = esc_html__( 'Enter a different address', 'woocommerce' );
        endif;
        ?>

        <?php if ( $show_package_details ) : ?>
            <?php echo '<p class="woocommerce-shipping-contents"><small>' . esc_html( $package_details ) . '</small></p>'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $show_shipping_calculator ) : ?>
            <?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator( $calculator_text ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```